# Tab gets half cuts at certain event like lock/unlock screen

Tags: android, android-layout, tabs

I used android default tab in android application.
I used tab at bottom of screen as we look in iphone app.
I am getting one issue with tab ,

- When screen lock/unlock , tab get half cut.

I tried hard to solve it myself but everything was useless.

Can anybody help me ?

Here you can look at my tab screen.

Before :

[image]

========
After screen unlock

[image]

Thanks in advance.